# HashMap<String, String> and others into an SQLiteDataBase

Tags: android, json, hashmap, sqlite

i've already searched to solve my problems with other topics, but i didn't found the good one. So i will explain what i want to do.
I recover on website a JSON file like this one :

```
{
    "prod": {
        "ean": "000000000000",
        "cat": "category ...",
        "title": "title ...",
        "brand": "brand ...",
        "intake": [
            {
                "carbohydrates": "10g"
            },
            {
                "protein": "8g"
            },
            {
                "lipids": "0g"
            }
        ],
        "others": "blablabla"
    }
}
```

I can parse it well, and show it in different fields like TextViews and I use a ListView to show the "intake" Array. And now i want to put all these values in a database. I can put everything in my DataBase except this Array (I use an HashMap). Knowing that the number of elements of this Array can vary,
someone have an idea how to proceed ?

Thanks, and I apologize for my bad english.
I can put more information if you ask me.

There is my DataBase Handler :

```
public class Base extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "etiquettesDatabase";

private static final String TABLE_ETIQUETTE = "etiquettes";

private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_BRAND = "brand";
private static final String KEY_INTAKE = "intake"; // i don't know how to proceed here
private static final String KEY_FAMILY = "family";
private static final String KEY_OTHERS = "others";

public Base(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ETIQUETTE + "("
                    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                    + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_BRAND + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_FAMILY + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_INTAKE + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_OTHERS + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ETIQUETTE);
    onCreate(db);
}

void addEtiquette(Etiquette etiquette) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, etiquette.get_titre());
    values.put(KEY_BRAND, etiquette.get_marque());
    values.put(KEY_FAMILY, etiquette.get_famille());
    //values.put(KEY_INTAKE, etiquette.get_nutrition());
    values.put(KEY_OTHERS, etiquette.get_autres());


    db.insert(TABLE_ETIQUETTE, null, values);
    db.close();
}

Etiquette getEtiquette(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;

    if (db != null) {
        cursor = db.query(TABLE_ETIQUETTE, new String[]{KEY_ID,
                KEY_TITLE, KEY_BRAND, KEY_INTAKE, KEY_OTHERS}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
    }
    Etiquette etiquette;
    /*
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst(); Log.v("test", "cursor /null");
        etiquette = new Etiquette(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(3),
                cursor.getClass(),
                cursor.getString(5)
                );
    } else {
        etiquette=null; Log.v("test", "etiquette = null");
    }
    */
    cursor.close();
    //Log.v("test", "cursor"+String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))));
/*
    Etiquette etiquette = new Etiquette(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1),
            cursor.getString(2),
            cursor.getString(3),
            cursor.getString(4));
*/
  //  return etiquette;
    return null;
}


public List<Etiquette> getAllEtiquettes() {
    List<Etiquette> etiquettesList = new ArrayList<Etiquette>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ETIQUETTE;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Etiquette etiquette = new Etiquette();
            etiquette.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            etiquette.set_titre(cursor.getString(1));
            etiquette.set_famille(cursor.getString(2));
            etiquette.set_marque(cursor.getString(3));
            //etiquette.set_nutrition(cursor.getString(4));
            etiquette.set_autres(cursor.getString(5));

            etiquettesList.add(etiquette);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return etiquettesList;
}


public int updateEtiquette(Etiquette etiquette) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, etiquette.get_titre());
    values.put(KEY_BRAND, etiquette.get_famille());
    values.put(KEY_OTHERS, etiquette.get_autres());
//    values.put(KEY_INTAKE, etiquette.get_nutrition());
    values.put(KEY_OTHERS, etiquette.get_autres());

    return db.update(TABLE_ETIQUETTE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(etiquette.get_id())});
}

public void deleteEtiquette(Etiquette etiquette) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_ETIQUETTE, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(etiquette.get_id())});
    db.close();
}

public int getEtiquettesCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ETIQUETTE;
    assert db != null;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int n = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();

    return n;
}

int getDATABASE_VERSION(){
    return this.DATABASE_VERSION;
}

void setDATABASE_VERSION(int newDATABASE_VERSION){
    this.DATABASE_VERSION = newDATABASE_VERSION;
}
}
```

Comment: whats your DB table structure ?

Comment: Wait for a minute, I edit my question to show you my DB Handler

Comment: There is my DB structure Renjith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in two ways.

First way:
**Introduce a new table for intake** use you id as a foreign key and store the intake and its value in that table and it will be easily accessible using a simple joint query.

Second way:
**Combine all intakes and values into a string with predefined separators**, and store it in your current field, and when retrieve it use the delimiters used to parse them and display as you like

```
String value_delimter = ":";
String intake_delimter = "&"
String intak_value = "intake1"+value_delimter +"value1"+intake_delimter 
"intake2"+value_delimter +"value2"+intake_delimter
"intake3"+value_delimter +"value3"+intake_delimter
```

You can access values while retrieving data using splits with the delimiters.

Comment: I will try the second one as Armaan Strange tell me :       
"carbohydrates:10g|protein:8g|lipids:0g"

Answer (score 1):

Create Special Character separated string from your array like this using loop

"carbohydrates:10g,protein:8g,lipids:0g"

and then put this whole string as your column value and when you are getting back try conmma separation and then colon separation to get your value.

Comment: I have to concatenate all my HashMap values into a String to do that? I don't understand what you really mean. Can you give me a little example please?

Comment: Yes you need to concatenate it with using string builder or anything else using separation character. and after all concatenation store that string in your database table's column. so it will be saved.

Comment: and when you retrieve string from that column then again split that string using separation characters to get exact data.